# Is there a way to detect when the native Google Chrome browser has finished translating an element on the page?

Tags: javascript, translate, speech

I have a project I am working on. It uses the built in speech recognition in Google Chrome.
However, I want to be able to use the native browser translate to another language and send the results to the Zoom Caption API URL.

Is there a way to detect when Google Chrome has finished translating an element?

For example if I use this code below, It will show the text being changed several times before Google Chrome stops changing it. Sometimes it will be 5 changes, sometimes 7 changes. I would like to detect when the native Google Chrome browser has finished translating an element so I can then use the translated text.

My project: https://engineer4business.com/other/speech-new.htm

```
$(lastEnteredParagraph).bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function () {
        console.log(`Last entered paragraph was changed to: ${lastEnteredParagraph.innerText}`);
        // This will fire several times because google translate does multiple changes, not all at once.
        // Should use: MutationObserver 
      });
```

Comment: although you can send requests of the text to translate.google.com and decode your stuff in batches of 5000 chars, it would be interesting to see a way to just KNOW if an element is translated using the browser translation stuff